# How get EntityManager to execute native sql

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

First of all, apologize for the grammatical errors that you can make. My English is not very good.

I'm creating a Table constructor to create dinamically tables.
My problem is that EntityManager is null and I dont know why.

I was reading that you can create an entityManager with an [entityManagerFactory](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/overview) and passing parameter that already I have in my application.properties.

Or I can inject PersistenceContext but when I try to execute a sql sentence, EntityManager is null.

How can I solve it?

EDIT:
I did all that you said and show next:

```
LOGGER.DEBUG:

CREATE TABLE countries( table_id SERIAL, tsunami int8, mag float8, felt numeric, id varchar(255), time bigint,  primary key (table_id));

ERROR:

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.project.maps.util.TableGeoJsonGenerator.executeSQL...
```

Sorry I Edit and add edited code to sort all code and editions:
Here is my code:

```
@Service
public class TableGeoJsonGenerator {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(SchemeService.class);

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    public TableGeoJsonGenerator() {
        super();
    }

    public void initTable(String name, List<String> columns, List<String> typeColumns, ArrayList<Object> rows) {
        createTableWithColumns(name, columns, typeColumns);
        addRowsInTable(rows);       
    }

    private void createTableWithColumns(String name, List<String> columns, List<String> typeColumns) {
        String SQL = "CREATE TABLE " + name + "( table_id int8 NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " + generateSqlColumns(columns, typeColumns) +" primary key (table_id));";
        LOGGER.debug(SQL);
        executeSQL(SQL);
    }

    private void addRowsInTable(ArrayList<Object> rows) {

    }

    public String generateSqlColumns(List<String> columns, List<String> typeColumns) {
        String DINAMIC_COLUMNS = "";
        for (int i=0; i<columns.size(); i++) {
            DINAMIC_COLUMNS += columns.get(i).toString() + " " + getPostgresqlValue(typeColumns.get(i).toString()) + ", ";
        }
        return DINAMIC_COLUMNS;
    }

    private void executeSQL(String SQL) {
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.createNativeQuery(SQL).executeUpdate();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch(Throwable e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                em.getTransaction().rollback();             
            }
            throw e;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    private String getPostgresqlValue(String value) {
        if (value.equals(Integer.class.toString())) {
            return "int8";
        } 
        else if (value.equals(Double.class.toString())) {
            return "float8";
        }
        else if (value.equals(String.class.toString())) {
            return "varchar(255)";
        }
        else if (value.equals(Long.class.toString())) {
            return "bigint";
        }
        else if (value.equals(Boolean.class.toString())) {
            return "boolean";
        }
        else if (value.equals(Date.class.toString())) {
            return "timestamp";
        }
        else {
            return "numeric";
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: You class `TableGeoJsonGenerator` must be a `Bean`. Place one of following annotations on you class: `@Component`, `@Service`. You should have an the `EntityManager` autowired after that.

Comment: When you are working with spring boot, usually, you don't need to create the `EntityManagerFactory` by yourself. If you set the right database parameters in your properties file, Spring Boot will automatically create an EntityManagerFactory Bean. Then in a Bean class you can get your EntityManager autowired with the `@PersistenceContext` annotation.

Comment: Service and Utility can not be at the same time:
Error creating bean with name 'tableGeoJsonGenerator' utility class and cannot be instantiated

Comment: I changed my code as you say @Grechka Vassili and entity manager is null

Comment: first, you don't need the constructor of your `TableGeoJsonGenerator ` class because spring-boot will generate one for you with you autowired EntityManager. Second, I'm pretty sure that you have a NPE because you are instantiating your `TableGeoJsonGenerator` directly via constructor. But, now your `TableGeoJsonGenerator ` class is a spring `Bean` so you must autowire it if you want to use it. Remeber, you can autowire `TableGeoJsonGenerator ` in a class that is a spring bean !

Comment: please show us how you use your `TableGeoJsonGenerator ` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@UtilityClass`

Im guessing this is your problem. Taken from lombok documentation.

> **A utility class cannot be instantiated**. By marking your class with @UtilityClass, lombok will automatically generate a private constructor that throws an exception, flags as error any explicit constructors you add, and marks the class final. If the class is an inner class, the class is also marked static.

My guess here is the following. Spring can only inject beans into spring managed objects. Your class `TableGeoJsonGenerator` is not a managed bean because spring can't instantiate it.

You need to remove `@UtilityClass` and add one of the managed bean annotations, like `@Service` `@Controller` etc. etc.

When defining jpa properties in `application.properties` spring boot will automatically create a `EntityManager` for you with the properties defined.

This can then be `@Autowired` into any `spring managed bean`. You need to make your class managed first.

Comment: I did as you can see in edited code but EntityManager continues being null, why? my class should extends another or implements something to have an EntityManager that not should be null??

Comment: well now we have solved one problem, the new problem is "why is an autowired bean null in a spring managed class". What you can do now is the following. We need to see your package structure. Make sure that your `@Service` anntoated class is in a package below your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. We also need the full null pointer error msg. You can check the logs that your `@Service` class gets picked up. I would also like to se the class that calls your `TableGeoJsonGenerator` does that class autowire in the generator or does it do "new"?

Comment: we need to see the full picture, not just a single class and an error msg.

Answer (score -3):

where is your methode entityManagerFactory() ?

I think : 
 + First, create the EntityManagerFactory

`EntityManagerFactory entitymanagerfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("your.package");`

- then, create entityManager :

  `public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
     return entitymanagerfactory .createEntityManager();
  }`

then :

```
     ...
     EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();

     em.getTransaction().begin();
     ....
```

Comment: I think that when you are using spring boot and you have your database configuration in the application.properties file you already have the entitymanager factory that you can autowire. You don't have to create it by yourself.

Comment: thanks! Now I create my EntityManagerFactory but throw an Exception: No persistence provider for EntityManager named com.application.maps. Why doesnt work with my package??

Comment: Yes, I'm using springboot but I use Autowire injection and doesnt work

Comment: Did you add to your pom : spring-orm, hibernate-core.

And use spring-boot-starter-parent as parent  ?